# Chid items not displaying in mat navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I wanted to render multiple level naviation using angular matrial design.

Below is the sample nav data,

```
navData=[{url:"/index",description:"Main Nav 1",children:[{url:"/index",description:"Sub Child 1"},{url:"/index",description:"Sub Child 2"},{url:"/index",description:"Sub Child 3"},{url:"/index",description:"Sub child 4",children:[{url:"/index",description:"Child 1 of Sub Child 4"}]},{url:"/index",description:"Sub Child 5",children:[{url:"/index",description:"Child 1 of Sub Child 5"}]},{url:"/index",description:"Sub Child 6"}]}];
```

In the sample data, It as `3` level.

Currently I'm displaying first level of navigation.

How to display it's child nav. Please help.

My StackBlitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xszcga?file=app/sidenav-overview-example.html

My HTML code,

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
        <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let nav of navData">
                {{nav.description}}
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-template` to nest `mat-nav-list` using `[ngForOf]` by accessing the children property of the upper levels of your navigation.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
        <mat-nav-list>
          <ng-template ngFor let-nav [ngForOf]="navData">
            <mat-list-item (click)="toggle(nav)">
              {{nav.description}}
            </mat-list-item>
            <ng-template [ngIf]="nav.open">
              <mat-nav-list>
                <ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="nav.children">
                  <mat-list-item (click)="toggle(child)">
                    {{child.description}}
                  </mat-list-item>
                  <ng-template [ngIf]="child.open">
                    <mat-nav-list>
                      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let child2 of child.children">
                        {{child2.description}}
                      </mat-list-item>
                    </mat-nav-list>
                  </ng-template>
                </ng-template>
              </mat-nav-list>
            </ng-template>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and add `toggle = nav => nav.open = !nav.open;` inside the component in your TS file

Comment: It's working, but not the way I wanted. I wanted a tree view like, if i click the main nav it should show the child and same goes to the sub child as well. any idea ?

Comment: Add a property `open` to each item, then add a `<ng-template [ngIf]="nav.open">` around the `<ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="nav.children">` with a toggle on a click event `<mat-list-item (click)="toggle(nav)">` implemented as `toggle = (item) => item.open = !item.open`. This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried like this `<mat-list-item>
        <button ariaControls="nav-list-{{i}}">{{nav.description}}</button>
      </mat-list-item>`

Comment: But the {{i}} is not relevant, so the childs are not getting insde the parent

Comment: ariaControl cannot control another element, it is only used to link elements and indicate their relation for people with sight helpers. I updated my answer to add the changes you want.

Comment: I've updated my mock, It need to be done via `ariaControl ` as coding standards. any help ? plz

Comment: If you need ariaControl you need to be able to identify each navigation menu uniquely. That means having a different unique id for each of them. I can't really help you more tho, as you need to determine how to do that based on your data structure.

Comment: I got one more issue with ur solution, If der are no child items, It still clickable also  der is somemovent while clicking https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xszcga?file=app%2Fsidenav-overview-example.ts. can you check.

Comment: Update the `ngIf` condition to `nav.open && nav.children` so nothing will happen if there's no children